# Controlling Windows Media Player Across User Accounts

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Can I control an instance playing on one user account from another user account on the same PC?
It's my PC! I use multiple accounts for different tasks, often jump between them, be nice to control the player from all accounts!